# How to Query elasticsearch index with nested and non nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an elastic search index with the following mapping:

```
PUT /student_detail
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "id" : { "type" : "long" },
            "name" : { "type" : "text" },
            "email" : { "type" : "text" },
            "age" : { "type" : "text" },
            "status" : { "type" : "text" },
            "tests":{ "type" : "nested" }
        }
    }
}
```

Data stored is in form below:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "Schwarb",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "status": "current",
  "age": 14,
  "tests": [
    {
      "test_id": 587,
      "test_score": 10
    },
    {
      "test_id": 588,
      "test_score": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to query the students where name like '%warb%' AND email like '%gmail.com%' AND test with id 587 have score > 5 etc. The high level of what is needed can be put something like below, dont know what would be the actual query, apologize for this messy query below

```
GET developer_search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tests",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tests.test_id": IN [587]
                    }
                  },
                   {
                    "term": {
                      "tests.test_score": >= some value
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query must be flexible so that we can enter dynamic test Ids and their respective score filters along with the fields out of nested fields like age, name, status

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
GET student_detail/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "*warb*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "email": {
              "value": "*gmail.com*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tests",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tests.test_id": 587
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "tests.test_score": {
                        "gte": 5
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Inner hits is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You must make use of [Ngram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) as wildcard search must not be used for performance reasons and I wouldn't recommend using it.

Change your mapping to the below where you can create your own [Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) which I've done in the below mapping.

How elasticsearch (albiet lucene) indexes a statement is, first it breaks the statement or paragraph into words or tokens, then indexes these words in the inverted index for that particular field. This process is called [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and that this would only be applicable on `text` datatype.

So now you only get the documents if these tokens are available in inverted index.

By default, [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) would be applied. What I've done is I've created my own analyzer and used Ngram Tokenizer which would be creating many more tokens than just simply words.

Default Analyzer on `Life is beautiful` would be  `life`, `is`, `beautiful`.

However using Ngrams, the tokens for `Life` would be `lif`, `ife` & `life`

### Mapping:

```
PUT student_detail
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 4,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "id" : { 
              "type" : "long" 
            },
            "name" : { 
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "email" : { 
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "age" : { 
              "type" : "text"             <--- I am not sure why this is text. Change it to long or int. Would leave this to you
            },
            "status" : { 
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "tests":{ 
              "type" : "nested" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the above mapping I've created a sibling field in the form of keyword for `name`, `email` and `status` as below:

```
"name":{ 
   "type":"text",
   "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
   "fields":{ 
      "keyword":{ 
         "type":"keyword"
      }
   }
}
```

Now your query could be as simple as below.

### Query:

```
POST student_detail/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "war"                      <---- Note this. This would even return documents having "Schwarb"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "email": "gmail"                   <---- Note this
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tests",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tests.test_id": 587
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "tests.test_score": {
                        "gte": 5
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that for exact matches I would make use of [Term Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) fields while for normal searches or `LIKE` in `SQL` I would make use of simple [Match Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) on [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) Fields ***provided*** they make use of `Ngram Tokenizer`.

Also note that for `>=` and `<=` you would need to make use of [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html).

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 233,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 3.7260926,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "student_detail",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 3.7260926,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 123,
          "name" : "Schwarb",
          "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
          "status" : "current",
          "age" : 14,
          "tests" : [
            {
              "test_id" : 587,
              "test_score" : 10
            },
            {
              "test_id" : 588,
              "test_score" : 6
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that I observe the document you've mentioned in your question, in my response when I run the query.

Please do read the links I've shared. It is vital that you understand the concepts. Hope this helps!